# Animate active and next elements depending on next parent direction

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have sections which contain an image div (with background image) and a button.

**THE PARENTS:**

When I say in the followings "previous section", it means the section active which is presently on screen.

The sections class name indicates from which part of the screen it will arrive on the screen ("from-down", "from-right", "from-up", "from-left").

The next section comes to screen when the previous section button (.next) is clicked.

The previous section leaves to the opposite direction of the next section.

Example:
if the next section is called "from-down", it comes from top:120% to top:0, the previous section is animated upto -120% top.

**THE CONTENTS:**

When the sections move, the image-contents move also to have a parallax effect.

All active parent images are absolute positioned with top:50% and left:50% and translate(-50%, -50%).

When the next parent section moves to screen and previous section leaves opposite direction, the image divs move also to the direction of their parent. It means that if the section moves to left, the image moves to 100% left.

Example:
if next parent is "from-down", the previous section img div moves upto top from top:50% to top:-50%, and the next section image divs move from top:150% to top:50%.

Example2:
If next parent is "from-right", the previous section img div moves to left from left:50% to left:-50%, and the next section image divs move from left:150% to left:50%.

**HTML structure:**

```
<section class="from-down scene1">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</section>
<section class="from-right scene2">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</section>
<section class="scene from-down scene3">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</section>
<section class="scene from-down scene4">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>
</section>
<!-- and so on...-->
```

**MY QUESTION:**

I am thinking to write the jQuery codes shorter instead of declare each .next button animation.
I must find/declare first :

1. the image div which is in the same previous (active) section where the active .next button is. I guess that will be the .closest('.image'),
2. the image div which is in the next section.
3. the next image parent (next section)

Then I should call them and animate. I thought about the if-else method but my codes do not work:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var nextImage = $(this).next('section .image');
    var thisImage = $(this).closest('.image');
    if (nextImage.parent('.from-down')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'-50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextImage.parent('.from-right')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'50%','left':'-50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextImage.parent('.from-up')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'150%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextImage.parent('.from-left')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'50%','left':'150%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    });
```

Comment: do you want like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ykodcg0L/2/

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant Non :) It is true, I did not explain the image movement enough, because the most important for me to find how I can declare and find the image in the same parent as the next button, also to declare the parent, and the next parent and the next parent image. I think you are concentrating more abt the image animation. I did not explain bcs I have even more images in my image div. Finally I found out the .next, .closest and if-else combination solution, here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/ab8fckrt/21/. Now my problem is with the first-second next/prev movement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found how to declare/find 1. the .image element in the same parent like the clicked next bttn element is located, also 2. the parent of the clicked next bttn element, 3. the next parent, and 4. the next parent .image element. Like that I can animate them, because I can know the direction of the next parent. I used .hasClass, .closest, and .next.

The right codes :

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var nextScene = $(this).closest('.scene').next();
    var nextImage = $(this).closest('.scene').next().find('.i');
    var thisImage = $(this).closest('.scene').find('.i');
    
    if (nextScene.hasClass('from-down')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'-50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextScene.hasClass('from-right')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'-50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextScene.hasClass('from-up')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'150%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextScene.hasClass('from-left')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'150%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
});
```

However I still have a problem when my first section has a different class name (not .scene) and its image is not animated. But it is another question, you can find my next step question here :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77524274/animate-this-element-next-parent-element-and-prev-parent-element-by-this-button](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77524274/animate-this-element-next-parent-element-and-prev-parent-element-by-this-button)