# Animate this element, next parent element and prev parent element by this button click

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I must give you a lot of information to undestand what is the problem with my simple jQuery codes.

**SECTIONS (PARENTS)**

- I have several sections. All contain an "*i*" element, a "*prev*" and a "*next*" button div (first has no prev bttn, last has no next bttn of course).
- All sections have a general class name called "*scene*", and have a class name which indicates the direction from where it arrived to the screen ("*from-down*", "*from-right*", "*from-up*", "*from-left*").
- All sections are 100% width and height (screen size), overflow hidden.
- Except the first section, which has the class name "*main*".

**.i ELEMENTS (PARENT ELEMENTS)**

The .i divs contain an "*img*" div, a "*fancy*" link, and a "*blur*" div, all are absolute positioned into the .i center with top and left: 50% and translate(-50%, -50%). All of them have a cover background image. They move together, so I do not want to go into details, the most important is to understand why I animate the .i element children to top-bottom or to left-right, it gives a parallax effect, a blur effect and when we click on it, the image is pop up in fancybox modal window.

Except the first, .main section, because its .i element does not include .img sub-element, and its .fancy and .blur elements are not animated, they are top:0 and left:0 always.

**HTML STRUCTURE:**

```
<section class="main">
    <div class="i">fancy blur divs...</div>
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</section>
<section class="from-down">
    <div class="i">img fancy blur divs...</div>
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</section>
<section class="from-right">
    <div class="i">img fancy blur divs...</div>
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</section>
<section class="scene from-up">
    <div class="i">img fancy blur divs...</div>
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</section>
<section class="scene from-left">
    <div class="i">img fancy blur divs...</div>
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</section>
<!-- and there are more sections with random "from-direction" order -->
```

**THE ANIMATION**

The main section is the start scene on screen. When you click on next bttn, the next section arrives from where its class name indicates. The from-down section from 120% top to 0 top, etc.
And in the meantime the .i children are moving in the same direction as the parent section. So the "from-down" .i children center move from 150% top to 50% top, etc.
When you click on prev bttn, everything goes the opposite exactly in the same order as logical.

**MY PROBLEM**

My codes are working, except at the first next animation when the main section leaves to top, and the 1st scene section arrives from bottom, and at the last prev animation when the 1st scene section leaves to bottom, and the main section arrives from top. The problem is with the .i children. At the next step, nothing happens, at the prev step the main .i children moves when they should not move. Certainly I did not declare the main section in the right way, or I thought also that I can not do it like that, only when its also a .scene section, but I do not know how to do the appropriate way.

**JQUERY CODES:**

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var thisMain = $(this).closest('.main');
    var nextMainImage = $(this).closest('.main').next().find('.i');
    /*var thisScene = $(this).closest('.scene');*/
    var nextScene = $(this).closest('.scene').next();
    var nextImage = $(this).closest('.scene').next().find('.i');
    var thisImage = $(this).closest('.scene').find('.i');
    
    if (thisMain.hasClass('main')) {
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    if (nextScene.hasClass('from-down')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'-50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextScene.hasClass('from-right')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'-50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextScene.hasClass('from-up')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'150%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (nextScene.hasClass('from-left')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'150%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        nextImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
});
$('.prev').click(function(){
    var prevMain = $(this).closest('.main').prev();
    var prevMainImage = $(this).closest('.main').prev().find('.i');
    var thisScene = $(this).closest('.scene').not('.main');
    var prevScene = $(this).closest('.scene').not('.main').prev();
    var prevImage = $(this).closest('.scene').not('.main').prev().find('.i');
    var thisImage = $(this).closest('.scene').not('.main').find('.i');
    if (prevMain.hasClass('main')) {
        if (thisScene.hasClass('from-down')) {
            thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'150%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }
        else if (thisScene.hasClass('from-right')) {
            thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'150%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }
        else if (thisScene.hasClass('from-up')) {
            thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'-50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }
        else if (thisScene.hasClass('from-left')) {
            thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'-50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        }
    }
    else {
    }
    if (thisScene.hasClass('from-down')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'150%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        prevImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (thisScene.hasClass('from-right')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'150%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        prevImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (thisScene.hasClass('from-up')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'-50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        prevImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
    else if (thisScene.hasClass('from-left')) {
        thisImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'-50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
        prevImage.delay(300).children().animate({'top':'50%','left':'50%'}, 5000, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
});
```

I made a similar fiddle here (only for having an idea, some codes are different): https://jsfiddle.net/igorlaszlo/ab8fckrt/23/